# Rock paper scissors, skipping a result

Tags: python, random

```
import random
for i in range(3):
user = str(input("Please enter your choice: "))
if (random.randrange(3)) == 0 :
    print("Computer chooses Rock")
    if user == "scissors" :
        print("computer wins")
    elif user == "paper" :
        print("player wins")
    else :
        print("tie")
elif (random.randrange(3)) == 1 :
    print("Computer chooses Paper")
    if user == "rock" :
        print("computer wins")
    elif user == "scissors" :
        print("player wins")
    else :
        print("tie")
elif (random.randrange(3)) == 2 :
    print("Computer chooses Scissors")
    if user == "paper" :
        print("computer wins")
    elif user == "rock" :
        print("player wins")
    else :
        print("tie")
```

The formatting is a bit weird on here (havent used this website before). I dont know the reason but i dont know why this code sometimes skips a result. if anyone could help that would be great.

This is what is produced when it is run a couple of times

```
enter your choice: scissors
Computer chooses Rock
computer wins
enter your choice: scissors
Computer chooses Scissors
tie
enter your choice: scissors
Computer chooses Rock
computer wins
================================ RESTART ================================ 
Please enter your choice: scissors
Please enter your choice: rock
Computer chooses Rock
tie
Please enter your choice: rock
Computer chooses Rock
tie
```

I dont understand why it skips a result. Seems to happen randomly

Comment: The computer is cheating... Allow just one random choice to it, _before_ you enter the chain of `if`s.  BTW  there are simpler ways to determine the outcome of one hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should not use `random.randrange(3)` three times. This may e.g. give you the following numbers: 1, 2 and then 0. So the code which is then executed would be:

```
if (1 == 0):
   ...
elif (2 == 1):
   ...
elif (0 == 2):
   ...
```

and none of the conditional blocks of the if statements would be executed.

Instead do something like this:

```
computerChoice = random.randrange(3)
...
if computerCoice == 0:
  ...
elif computerChoice == 1:
  ...
elif computerChoice == 2:
  ...
else
  raise Exception("something is definitively wrong here")
```

Comment: How do you suggest i fix it? assign random to a variable?

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry i was being a mug.

Answer (score 2):

you have used `random.randrange(3)` multiple times and each time there is a possibility of it being a different number.. So i would suggest you assign the value to a variable and then use that in your `if` statements:

```
x = random.randrange(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you've accepted the excellent answer of Andre, that takes you to understand clearly your error.  As I commented your Q saying that there are simpler ways to award a hand, here it is my take

```
import random

c = random.randrange(3)
u = int(input('1=scissors, 2=paper, 3=rock: '))-1

if u==c:
    print '... tie ...'
elif (u==0 and c==1) or (u==1 and c==2) or (u==2 and c==0):
    print 'User wins!'
else:
    print 'Computer wins... Booh!'
```

but I'm not sure if it is simpler... shorter for sure it is, but simpler?

One can make it even shorter

```
import random

def hand():
    c = random.randrange(3)
    u = int(input('1=scissors, 2=paper, 3=rock: '))-1
    print "User played",['scissors,', 'paper,', 'rock,'][u],
    print "computer played",['scissors.', 'paper.', 'rock.'][c]
    print ['Tie.', 'User wins!', 'Computer wins...'][(c-u)%3]
```

This is an example session:

```
>>> hand()
1=scissors, 2=paper, 3=rock: 3
User played rock, computer played scissors.
User wins!
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is happening randomly. :)

```
if (random.randrange(3)) == 0 :
  # computer "chooses" a random number
elif (random.randrange(3)) == 1 :
  # now the computer's choice is a new choice from 0..2
elif (random.randrange(3)) == 2 :
  # and now it's different again
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here :

`if (random.randrange(3)) == 0 :
  elif (random.randrange(3)) == 1 :
  elif (random.randrange(3)) == 2 :`

In the if statement random.randrange(3) will generate a random number if it doesn't match, it will go to  elif statement and random.randrange(3) will **generate another random number** and it may not be the same as the previously generated random number . Some time because of this your code will skip one , two , three or  none of the statement .

If you want your code to be good , you should assign the random number to an integer and then use that integer in your answer .

It should be

`ran=random.randrange(3)
   if ran == 0 :
   elif ran == 2 :
   elif ran == 3 :`